# Is there any way to trigger a special mouse event when mouse is static inside the div box?

Tags: javascript, css

Given a div box, suppose we want to show a tooltip if the mouse is static inside for a while, showing the tooltips under the mouse cursor, once the mouse moved, the tooltip will disappear.

I want to know is there any way to simulate this? As we know, mouseover is triggered only when enter the box.

Comment: Use `mousemove` and a `setTimeout`. Clear the timeout / start the timeout over everytime the mouse moves. And in the timeout you do what you have to do.

Comment: The usual trick is to start a timeout (say 200ms) when the mouse enters the div, and cancel it if the mouse moves outside before the timeout fires.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, add an eventlistener to the document that listens for a mousemove. In that event do a `setTimeout` that gets cleared / starts over everytime you move the mouse. If the `setTimeout` runs, it means the mouse hasn't moved for x seconds.

```
var t;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    if (t) clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('mouse hasn\'t moved for 5 seconds');
    }, 5000);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qvy83pw/)

Comment: I wouldn't use mousemove: 1. showing the tooltip would require the user to stay absolutely still, which is usually not the case, and 2. it would evaluate on **every** mousemove, and that's just a waste of resources...

Comment: 1: That is what OP wants. 2: I agree, could have been better.

Comment: Yes, continuously trigger the mousemove will cause performance issue.